# Where is source code for default model binder for decimal in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for source code for default model binder for decimal in asp.net mvc 4.
I searched assemblies with dotpeek, but I cannot find it.

Where it is placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `decimal` instances are bound using the `DefaultModelBinder` class, which source you can find here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs